# How to put an empty array into a template string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a function that generates some react code for me

heres my function, it takes an object and creates a bunch of useState() hooks for me

```
var fromStateToHook = (obj) => {
    return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key,value]) => {
        return [...acc, [`const [${key}, 
        set${key.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)}] = useState('${value}');`]];
    }, []).join("\n")
}
```

when I use this like this

```
copy(fromStateToHook( {
    images: [],
}))
```

I get back this

```
const [images, setImages] = useState('');
```

I want to get this instead

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

**Is there any way to put an array into the template string?**

Comment: You could probably do it using a tagged template string instead of a template literal. They can return non-strings. Link to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array needs to be "stringified" in the way you would expect it to be written. Assuming it's a 1-dimensional array, [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) would do

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const template = `useState([${numbers.join(',')}])`
console.log(template); // useState([1,2,3,4])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
set${key.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)}] = useState(${JSON.stringify(value)});`]];
```

It really depends on how you want the value to be printed (transformed into text). If your needs are more complex, you will have to come up with a custom stringification mechanism for the value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you really need to generate code for that? You could also just create your own hook:

```
  function useStates(obj) {
    const result = {};
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      const [stored, setter] = useState(value);
      result[key] = stored;
      result["set" + key[0].toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)] = setter;
    }
   return result;
 }

 const { images, setImages, names, setNames } = useStates({ images: [], names: [] });
```